# Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
    $search_record = $_GET['search'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM semester_result,SUBJECT,std_reg WHERE semester_result.sub_id=subject.sub_id AND 
              semester_result.student_id = std_reg.student_id AND std_reg.roll_no='$search_record' ";

    $run = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    if ($run->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run))
        {
            $name = $row['fname'];
            $lname = $row['lname'];
            $sub=['subject_name'];
            echo $sub_id=['mid_mrks'];

?>
```

When I echo `$name` or `$lname` it works fine, but when I echo `$sub` or `$sub_id` it shows the following error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\semester\content\result.php on line 49.

Comment: `$sub = $row['subject_name']`.

Answer (score 1):

That error is due to passing an array variable to the `echo()` function, rather than a string.

In your example changing:

```
    $sub=['subject_name'];
```

to:

```
    $sub=$row['subject_name'];
```

will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
$name = $row['fname'];
$lname = $row['lname'];
$sub = $row['subject_name'];
echo $sub_id = $row['mid_mrks'];
```

I think you forgot `$row` in front of `['subject_name']`